# How to turn an argb pixel array into an SDL surface?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

Using C and SDL2, I have a pixel array with an ARGB8888 format.

```
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *) malloc (sizeof(Uint32)*(Uint32)windowWidth*(Uint32)windowHeight);
```

I want to put all that pixel information into a new `SDL_Surface` ready to save as a `.bmp`. How do I do this?

I'm unsure because new surfaces have RGBA8888 format and sdl convert functions require an existing surface to convert to a new surface. And there is no function which simply passes all pixel array values to a surface, so I know it will involve some sort of loop which assigns the pixels one by one.

Comment: [`SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat) followed by a [`SDL_ConvertPixels()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertPixels) to fill it?

Comment: @genpfault When I use `CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat`, my compiler (clang) says 'undefined reference' to that function. Do I need to `#include` something other than `SDL2`?

Comment: @genpfault Also `SDL_ConvertPixels` says it has a source and destination pointer. Does that mean I need two pointer arrays, two surfaces, or can I use my pixel array as the source and my new surface as the destination pointer?

Comment: `CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat()` isn't a SDL function, `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat()` is.  Note the `SDL_` prefix.

Comment: Use the `SDL_Surface::pixels` pointer from the `SDL_Surface` you got from `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat()` as the destination argument for `SDL_ConvertPixels()`

Comment: @genpfault Sorry, I was too lazy to add "SDL_" in my comment. It is in my code though. I'm using C, I don't know C++ so `::` doesn't make sense to me. I would try using `SDL_ConvertPixels()` but currently my compiler isn't letting me compile due to the first function causing an 'undefined reference' error.

Comment: I found out `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat()` isn't available to me as I am running SDL 2.0.3 I had to make two surfaces and then convert the pixels from one to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually save bitmap bits to a file. Bitmap files are usually 24bit or less, and bitmap viewers tend to ignore alpha. The code below assumes `bits` is 32-bit pixels. If you need 24-bit format, the input has to be converted from ARGB to RGB, and you must also account for padding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct my_BITMAPFILEHEADER {
    uint16_t bfType;
    uint32_t bfSize;
    uint16_t bfReserved1;
    uint16_t bfReserved2;
    uint32_t bfOffBits;
}my_BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct my_BITMAPINFOHEADER {
    uint32_t biSize;
    int32_t  biWidth;
    int32_t  biHeight;
    uint16_t biPlanes;
    uint16_t biBitCount;
    uint32_t biCompression;
    uint32_t biSizeImage;
    int32_t  biXPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t  biYPelsPerMeter;
    uint32_t biClrUsed;
    uint32_t biClrImportant;
}my_BITMAPINFOHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

int copy(uint8_t* bits, int width, int height, int bitcount)
{
    //compiler test:
    if(sizeof(my_BITMAPFILEHEADER) != 14 && sizeof(my_BITMAPINFOHEADER) != 40)
    {
        printf("bitmap structures not packed properly\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //width_in_bytes is roughly w * bytes_per_pixel, it takes padding in to account
    int width_in_bytes = ((width * bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4;    
    uint32_t imagesize = width_in_bytes * height;   
    my_BITMAPFILEHEADER filehdr = { 0 };
    my_BITMAPINFOHEADER infohdr = { 0 };
    memcpy(&filehdr, "BM", 2);
    filehdr.bfSize = 54 + imagesize;
    filehdr.bfOffBits = 54;
    infohdr.biSize = 40; 
    infohdr.biPlanes = 1;
    infohdr.biWidth = width;
    infohdr.biHeight = height;
    infohdr.biBitCount = bitcount;
    infohdr.biSizeImage = imagesize;

    FILE *fout = fopen("test.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite(&filehdr, sizeof(filehdr), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&infohdr, sizeof(infohdr), 1, fout);
    fwrite((char*)bits, 1, imagesize, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    return 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
copy(bits, width, height, 32);
//or
copy(bits, width, height, 24);
```